# I2C Primitive Sunfction for Python & Pi

Tags: python, i2c

Well-versed in C/C++, but new to Python.

I have done a lot of research here and maybe I am missing something, but it seems that Pi/Python does not have primitive functions for I2C, which is sad to be honest. If this is the case, then I don't understand why the foundation would not support bare-bone I2C. There are some work around's for different cases, but they do not solve all, and with some primitive functions, it could.

Here is one case: 16-bit REG_ADDR WRITE, but doesnt solve 16-bit REG_ADDR READ:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=170062

**Here is what is not possible:**

- A sensor with 16-bit registers, and 16-bit data. I am not talking about the slaver address. I see a ton of threads where people go back and forth on this subject and mix the 2.
- 7-bit/8-bit slave address
- 16-bit register offsets
- 16-bit data in each offset

How can I communicate with such a device? IS it possible?

- As soon as you want to read, all of the read functions, take an 8-bit read address, thus even if you could write the offset address before a read, the read will fail.

`read_block_data(SLAVE_ADDR, REG_ADDR, DATA_ARRAY[])` the REG_ADDR is always 8-bits, hence you cannot talk to a 16-bit address part.

**Is there a module someone has to just have primitive write and read functions?**

- write a byte array: `write(SLAVE_ADDR, BYTEARRAY[])`
- read a byte array:    `Array = read(SLAVE_ADDR)`

Why is this not available?

Comment: See this please: Again, never a read example, no explanation of these parameters.

http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-python/i2c-programming-in-python/using-the-i2c-interface-2

long[] read_block_data(int addr,char cmd) #this is in C, but I assume this is available, but what is the cmd parameter? offset? # of bytes? the other functions it's offset, but then how do you know how many read?

Where is the official documentation for this? I found something once before but it was horribly incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a number of issues.

The Pi only really supports 7-bit I2C slave addresses.  This isn't normally a problem as you hardly ever come across anything other than 7-bit I2C address devices.  I never have.

That has nothing to do with whether the device uses 16-bit or 8-bit (or any other number of bits) for internal register addresses or has 8-bit or 16-bit internal storage size.  **I2C always transfers in units of 8-bit bytes.**  So to read/write a 16-bit register you transfer two bytes.

The Python SMBus module only supports SMBus commands (with a couple of irrelevant to this answer exceptions).  This is okay for most but not all I2C devices.

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library does offer I2C as well as SMBus support.

The I2C support is for arbitrary length read and write of bytes.

For Python see [i2c_read_device](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#i2c_read_device) and [i2c_write_device](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#i2c_write_device).

Comment: Thanks for responding, I never really mentioned anything other than a slave address of 8-bits. This is about using a pi ... with python, and using their smbus lib to write (& READ) multiple bytes, from a device which has 16-bit register addresses. you can use the original smbus lib to fake out the multiple byte read to this type of device, but you cannot read, due to the 8-bit parameter for the reg address.

Comment: Okay, I made an incorrect assumption about questioning the slave address.  However I have answered the only relevant one of your many questions.

Comment: What device are you using that uses 16-bit register addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Hi This may be the answer to use PIGPIO, however it is not being found after installations. I followed the directions to download the zip, unzip, make & install. I think I may have an issue with directories.

** using Python v3.5, on a Pi Zero W.

Thanks,
-P

Comment: daemon? why? why hasn't anyone just written a simplified linux i/f for I2c?